# Mi paquete custom de laravel (composer) me da error

Tags: laravel, composer, packages

estaba instalando un paquete que de **composer** propio, lo he creado en la raiz del proyecto de laravel en este path : `[mi_proyecto]/packages/josanangel/miPaquete` , luego lo he instalado con el `require` , en principio bien.

> Mi idea en un principio es tener un paquete que al instalarlo deje un
> comando disponible en el proyecto

De hecho me voy al vendor de mi proyecto y ahi esta el paquete :

```
root@a9027c71bd5e:/var/www/html/app# ls vendor/josanangel/how_fast
HowFastServiceProvider.php  composer.json  src
```

Tambien he añadido esto a mi proyecto, en el `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/josanangel/how_fast",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

Para que sepa donde esta , el siguiente paso seria añadirlo en los **providers de mi proyecto** dentro de `config/app.php`:

```
...............
...............
...................        
josanangel\how_fast\HowFastServiceProvider::class
............
],
```

Y es en este paso donde falla, ya que cuando lo pongo ahi hago un `php artisan:optimize` o un `composer dump-autoload` (por hacer algo) y me da un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de mi paquete es :

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "josanangel/how_fast",
    "description": "Desc",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "José Ángel CRN",
            "email": "jose@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "josanangel\\how_fast\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

HowFastServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace josanangel\how_fast;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use josanangel\how_fast\Console\OptAnalysis;

class HowFastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        $this->commands([
            OptAnalysis::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

src/Console:

```
<?php

namespace josanangel\how_fast\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class OptAnalysis extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'howfast:test';
    protected $description = 'Descripción de tu comando';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Comando de pruebaaa');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que estoy creando todo con un docker con **php8.1** y **laravel9** , con un volumen compartido, que no se si peude que me este liando con los namespaces o algo al combinar el volumen de mi windows con el linux del docker.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error, el problema es que `HowFastServiceProvider.php` deberia de estar dentro de la carpeta `src` de mi paquete, lo he movido ya funciona.

Esta es la estructura valida :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]